# I need help animating this svg on hover

Tags: css, svg

I am having trouble animating this SVG on hover.

I can get the circle to animate, however I want it so when you hover over the icon, the whole icon animates in.

Pen is here
http://codepen.io/dterr009/pen/VmyWBW

```css
.st0 {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #e18a26;
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke-miterlimit: 10;
    stroke-dasharray: 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 200;
    animation: dash 2s ease forwards;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.st0:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the animation on st0 won't work. At best it will result in only the particulat st0 element you are hovering over to animate.

You need to add the hover rule and animation to the `<svg>` element itself.

```css
.st0{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#e18a26;
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}

svg {
  stroke-dasharray: 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 200;
}

svg:hover{
  animation: dash 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.start{
  fill:none;
  stroke:#007bc3;
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
  animation: changecolor .5s ease forwards;
  animation-play-state:paused;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

.start:hover{
  animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes changecolor {
  from {stroke: #007bc3;}
  to {stroke: #e18a26;}
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 21.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  xml:space="preserve">

 <circle class="start" cx="6.9" cy="56.6" r="5.2"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="57" cy="56.6" r="5.2"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="6.9" cy="7.4" r="5.2"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="57" cy="7.4" r="5.2"/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="12.5,56.6 24.5,56.6 24.5,45.6  "/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="52.5,56.6 40.4,56.6 40.4,45.6  "/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="52.5,7.1 40.4,7.1 40.4,18.1  "/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="12.5,7.1 24.5,7.1 24.5,18.1  "/>
 <rect x="19.4" y="18" class="st0" width="25.9" height="27.6"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="6.9" cy="32" r="5.2"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="57" cy="32" r="5.2"/>
 <line class="st0" x1="45.4" y1="32" x2="51.3" y2="32"/>
 <line class="st0" x1="13" y1="32" x2="18.8" y2="32"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="57.1" cy="56.6" r="5.2"/>
 <circle class="st0" cx="57.1" cy="7.4" r="5.2"/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="23,22.5 40.4,22.5 40.4,37.2  "/>
 <polyline class="st0" points="24.5,25.8 24.5,40.4 42,40.4  "/>
</svg>
```